# c++11: why is "auto&" not inferred to the correct type?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-inference

I have the following code:

```
struct MyType{};
using vec_type = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyType>>;
void foo(vec_type vec, vec_type& vec2, vec_type::iterator itr){
  for (auto &ri = vec.rbegin(); ri != vec.rend(); ++ri) {
    vec2.insert(itr, std::move(*ri));
  }    
}
```

It gets the following error at the for loop line:

```
non-const lvalue reference to type 'reverse_iterator<[...]>' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'reverse_iterator<[...]>'
```

Then I need to change to the following in order for it to compile:

```
vector<unique_ptr<Titem> >::reverse_iterator ri = replaces.rbegin();
for (; ri != vec.rend(); ++ri) {
    vec2.insert(itr, std::move(*ri));
}
```

This does not make sense to me - I do not see any semantic difference between the two codes. Shouldn't compiler just infers that "auto" is `vector<unique_ptr<Titem> >::reverse_iterator`?

I am using clang++ 3.5.

Comment: example edited to be simple, self contained, and compiles down to demonstrated error message.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Get rid of the ampersand. You want a copy of the iterator, not a reference to it.

```
for (auto ri = vec.rbegin(); ri != vec.rend(); ++ri) {
```

The compiler won't assign a temporary value to a non-const reference.